# How to consume GraphQL API from Nativescript Core application?

Tags: graphql, nativescript, apollo-client

I am trying to consume GraphQL ApI from nativescript core application but whole docs and tutorials are around nativescript angular and apollo.

Is it possible?, any recommendations about how to start?

Comment: Did you try [apollo-client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client)?

Comment: @Manoj no I will give a try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine with [apolli-client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client) as @Manoj recommended

Comment: how to implement it to nativescript-vue? (https://stackoverflow.com/q/60349985/11993949)